# Splash-screen via Android Studio

Tags: android, splash-screen

Im trying to build a splash-screen for my android app that includes a background image. My issue is that I can see the image fitting very well in the designer tab in Android Studio but when I run the app into my physical device the image is not there, just a black screen.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@Drawable/splash_1">
</LinearLayout>

public class Splash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        int myTimer = 10000; //Muuttuja "myTimer" määrittää kauan splash näkyy
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    //Muuttuja "i" käskee avaamaan MainActivity
                    Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }, myTimer);
    }}
```

So I did edit my layout a little bit- but still not working

Comment: Don't waste 10s of your users' time each time the run your app. Do it once, and they'll be annoyed. Do it twice, and they'll uninstall.

Comment: I believe the 10s is for testing only, but i concur: splash screen is evil, don't use it. Your users want to get to business quickly not to wait for a splash screen.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using specific dimensions for width and height. What happens is that your device has smaller screen than what you specified and the system 'pushes' the image on the next line (where line is computed as the height of the image in this case).

Set both width and height of the image to `match_parent` and add

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

or

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

depending on which you like.

Also remove the `orientation` attribute from `ImageView`, it only makes sense on `LinearLayout` element.

Note:
Your `MainActivity` may launch after 10 seconds even if you press the back button on the splash screen. There is a fix for this - see here: [Kill intent on splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26821689/kill-intent-on-splash-screen/26823120#26823120)

**EDIT** - Suggested layout:

```
<ImageView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:scaleType="centerCrop"
  android:src="@drawable/splash_1"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing, but I can't still get the image to show up on my Galaxy S4, even with those new lines.

Comment: Can you edit the whole activity_splash layout into your question?